# Insert big text into multiply rows by keyword into Excel or google spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

If I have multiline text like

```
Line:
x1 = 10, y1 = 100
x2 = 30, y2 = 40
Line:
x1 = 100, y1 = 120
x2 = 130, y2 = 140
```

And so on. Is it possible to insert it at once at Excel or google spreadsheets so every Line: with it's coordinates would be in different cell on different row?

Comment: It may help if you can mockup the result you want. From my reading,  you have exactly the text shown in your question and you want it to end up like either column A or B in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbh3D.png). If that's the case, you can edit the original text to wrap text in quotation marks. How you do that may vary, but you want a result like [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DXkP.png). You can copy / paste that into Excel to get the result shown in Column A of the first screenshot.

Comment: @EngineerToast wow, yes, it's exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot! You can write it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your original text and wrap all the lines you want in a single cell in quotation marks. The result should look like this:

```
"Line:
x1 = 10, y1 = 100
x2 = 30, y2 = 40"
"Line:
x1 = 100, y1 = 120
x2 = 130, y2 = 140"
```

How you do this is dependent on what you use to edit text. If I was using notepad++, I would find and replace like this:

[image: Replace]

Be sure to check the first and last lines of your text manually. If the replace I did above, it would have missed those two lines since they don't fit the pattern.

Once your text has quotes in it, you can copy / paste into Excel and it'll recognize everything between quotes as belonging in the same cell although it may not automatically resize rows and columns to fit your new data.

[image: Excel]